# Is it possible to see the events not only in the last 30 minutes in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

[image]

as you can see in the image Above in the right side, I can see the keywords of search item. but it seems that I can only track the searched keyword only for the last 30 minutes.

Is it possible to see the events not only in the last 30 minutes ? I mean I want to track for example in the last 7 days. how to do that ? I use it on my Android and my iOS app.

Comment: Hey, did you find any answer to this?

Comment: i can see this result sometimes on the dashboard not regularly. Can you tell me any reason why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

According to Firebase (contacted them by email):

> Please take note that custom events are not retroactive. This means that data will only start to flow in the reports after you have registered them. You may dive a little deeper into this matter in this [article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522/events?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) (Firebase - Events), and this [article for custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209/ga4-custom-dimensions-and-metrics?hl=en&visit_id=637584071773193036-3719553918&rd=1) ([GA4] Custom dimensions and metrics).

What this means is that there's no ComboBox for selecting the time period on the page on your screenshot.
You have to create custom dimensions and metrics.

Screenshot from one of the above articles:
[Screenshot from GA4 - Custom dimensions and metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSDos.png)

Answer (score -2):

Once Firebase Analytics is initialized, it keeps logging the event of the app which is logged with a bundle. However, it takes sometime for Firebase SDK to send the loggings to the server. As it is stated in your screen shot, it is actually showing the event of last 28 days.

I guess why you are not seeing the events of last 30 min is that Firebase SDK might have not send the logging events to the server yet.

If you are eager to see what's happening you might want to use DEBUG mode