# Firebase analytics with new UI not showing event details like item_id and item_name

Tags: xamarin, firebase-analytics

We have integrated firebase analytics in our mobile app, and we have added multiple log events, like below,

*CrossFirebaseAnalytics.Current.LogEvent(EventName.SelectContent, new Parameter(ParameterName.ContentType, "abc"),

new Parameter(ParameterName.ItemId, name + ":" + heading),

new Parameter(ParameterName.ItemName, url));*

We are able to see the details of the event for select_content like item_id and item_name within "events in last 30 mins", however we are not able to see it if we choose to see for last 30 days, earlier it used to show the detailed information for events.

Could anyone please guide us on this?

Thanks!!

Comment: This link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521363/is-it-possible-to-see-the-events-not-only-in-the-last-30-minutes-in-firebase-ana) has the same problem as you, hope it can help you.